# Using include and exclude in the jar command in gradle does not include all of the classes needed

Tags: java, build.gradle

I need to create a jar from a subset of java classes in my project.
I have 3 tasks: (Copy, Compile, Jar)
The copy and compile tasks work fine.
They are below for reference:
    1. Copy files to a directory that are needed to compile the jar.  There are additional files needed in this directory that are needed in the compile but not included in the jar files.

```
 task copyCoreSharedFiles(type: Copy) {
        includeEmptyDirs = false
        from ('src/java/com/')
    (List of includes and excludes) 
        into  rootProject.rootDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/target" +"/coreshared"
        println 'Copied core-shared files into directory'   
    }
2. Compile the java files and stored to another directory


 task compileCoreShareJar(type: JavaCompile) {
        source = file('target/coreshared')
        destinationDir = file('target/buildtmp/core')
        classpath = configurations.compile
        println 'Compiled core-shared files into directory' 
    }
```

I am having trouble jarring all of the class files.
The task in below.

```
task jarCoreShareClassFiles(type: Jar) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    archiveName = "core-shared-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    destinationDir = file("$rootDir/target/lib/")
    from file('target/buildtmp/core')
    include('**/com/common/*')
    include('**/com/javaserver/*')
    exclude('**/com/javaserver/dock/transaction/PrintTransaction.class')

    println 'Jar core-shared files into directory'
}
```

I need to include and exclude specific directories and files.
When I use `include('**/com/common/*')` it includes the **common** directory files but not the subdirectory **local** under the **common** directory.
It does not include the **javaserver** directory at all.

How do I use `include` and `exclude` in the jar command?

Comment: Well, `*` matches only one level. It does not go into subdirectories.

Comment: OK...good to know!

Comment: That's all I needed to know...got it building.  Please add your comment as an answer so I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` pattern does not match subdirectories. To recurse into subdirectories you can use `**`.